# jconsole.jar is missing in OpenJDK 10

Tags: java

I cannot build our java project with OpenJDK 10 cause of a missing system system lib.

I have to change the JDK from Oracle JDK 1.8.x up to OpenJDK 10.0.2. We are using Maven 3 as build and dependency management tool and we are also using the wildfly-maven-plugin (2.0.0.Final) to start a wildfly instance (14.0.1) at maven build for our integration tests.

The wildfly-maven-plugin needs the system lib 'jconsole.jar' which is usually in the lib folder of the jdk installation. But this file doesn't exists in OpenJDK 10 and I get this error message at the maven build:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project helwor-integration: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.zoink:helwor-integration:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/../lib/jconsole.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has nothing to do with the `wildfly-maven-plugin`. To verify, you can check if the [`pom.xml` from version 2.0.0.Final](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/blob/2.0.0.Final/pom.xml) depends on the path `/usr/lib/jvm...` - it does not. I would rather take a look into your project's `pom.xml` file(s) and try to remove that dependency.